# Consulta PHP con codeigniter, Cont sobre inventario

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estoy trabajando sobre una base de datos de la cual traigo varios campos de un sistema de inventario, lo que necesito es contar cuantos productos hay por caja. Para eso lo e intentado de varias formas, las cuales hasta ahora no soy muy eficientes por la cantidad de cajas que tiene el sistema.

```
<?php foreach($custodias as $custodia):?>
 if($custodia['caja_custodia'] == "1")
    {
        $suma = $suma+ 1; 
    } 
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Hasta ahora eso funciona pero son muchas cajas, y repetir el código por cada una no es la mejor forma de realizar esta operación.
la lista viene ordenada desde el modelo de mi sistema por lo cual mi idea es consultar por las cajas e ir contándolas hasta que el valor siguiente sea distinto e ir consignando el N° de la caja con su contador algo asi:

- CAJA 1: 63
- CAJA 2: 82

Para lo cual e intentado lo siguiente sin resultados positivos.

```
while ($custodia[$a] <= $custodia[$a]+1) {

       $cont = $cont + 1;
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto imagen la idea es mostrar al final: ej. Caja Z9 = 1, Caja Z81 = 3, Caja Z8 = 10 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo resolvería, con un array contador cuya clave es la caja y el valor el número de artículos. Te lo explico a continuación:

```
<?php 
$cajas = array();

foreach($custodias as $custodia){
  //Si no existe en el array contador la caja, la inicializamos a 1.
  if(! isset($cajas[$custodia['caja_custodia']]){

    $cajas[$custodia['caja_custodia']] = 1;
  }//en el caso opuesto sumamos un artículo a lo que había
  else{

    $cajas[$custodia['caja_custodia']]++;
  }
}

//Aquí ahora tenemos los valores caja => articulos de la siguiente forma:
foreach($cajas as $caja => $articulos){
  echo "Caja: $caja = $articulos artículos";
}
?>
```

Pienso que para tu problema esta es la solución correcta.
Saludos.

Comment: Disculpa creo que me equivoqué y te contará una caja de menos. Porque la inicialización de la caja debe ser 1 y no 0 como te puse, lo edito.

Answer (score 1):

Esto se resuelve con cortes de control. (El array tiene que estar ordenado por `caja_custodia`, que entiendo es así)

```
<?php 
 $resultado = array();
 $cajaAnterior = $custodias[0]['caja_custodia'];
 $suma = 0;
 foreach($custodias as $custodia):?>
   if($custodia['caja_custodia'] !== $cajaAnterior){
        $resultado[$cajaAnterior] = $suma;
        $suma = 0;
        $cajaAnterior = $custodia['caja_custodia'];
   }
   $suma = $suma+ 1;  
 endforeach;
 $resultado[$cajaAnterior] = $suma;
```

En `$resultado` te queda el array con tel total por caja.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda agregue un ejemplo de lo que necesito hacer adjuntando una imagen de la información que me da ahora el sistema y como necesito visualizar el resultado.

Comment: Estas modificando tu pregunta original que era como obtener la cantidad de items de cada caja sumando un item por cada vez que se repite la caja en la lista. En todo caso abrí otra pregunta con lo que necesitas ahora.